# Assigning event handler in a loop -- strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I am using jQuery to assign event handler to a buch of elements within a div. When I am using the jQuery 'native' `on` or `click` method on a single element, everything works. However, when I try to do it within a loop, nothing happens.

I have the following code that does not work:

```
$tags = $("#some_div p");
var len = $tags.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    $tags[i].on('click', function(){ alert("hi"); });
}
```

and this code that does work:

```
$tags = $("#some_div p");
var len = $tags.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    $tags[i].onclick = function() { alert("hello"); };
}
```

I have tried also `onclick(function()...)` in the first case, and I have tried `$.forEach` but the behaviour is always the same. I have created a JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fM2ar/

I don't have much experience with jQuery, but my reading of the documentation is that the first method should work -- any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In case you are not aware, `$("#some_div p").on('click', function() { alert("hello"); });` jQuery does all the looping for you.  Delegating to the container with `$("#some_div").on('click', 'p', function() { alert("hello"); });` has the advantage of attaching just one handler for all the contained `<p>` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$tags[i]` gives you a DOMElement, not a jQuery object. [`onclick` is a DOM property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.onclick), which is why it works. [`on()` is a jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/on), which is why it doesn't work.

Simply wrap your DOMElement in a jQuery object to use the `on()` method;

```
$($tags[i]).on('click', function(){ alert("hi"); });
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`eq(i)` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq), which returns the element at position `i`, wrapped in a jQuery object;

```
$tags.eq(i).on('click', function(){ alert("hi"); });
```

Comment: Don't all DOM objects have an `onclick` property?

Comment: So surely setting `$tags[i].onclick` is the same as saying, `var elem = document.getElementById("someID"); elem.onclick = ....`?

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no need for a `for` loop :

```
$("#some_div p").on('click', function() {
    alert( this.innerHTML );
});
```